# Can't view div in browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var gameBoard;
const huPlayer = 'O';
const aiPlayer = 'X';
const winCombos = [

 [0, 1, 2],
 [3, 4, 5],
 [6, 7, 8],
 [0, 3, 6],
 [1, 4, 7],
 [2, 5, 8],
 [0, 4, 8],
 [6, 4, 2]

]

const cells = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');
startGame();

function startGame() {
 document.querySelector(".endgame").style.display = "none";
 gameBoard = Array.from(Array(9).keys());

 for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
  cells[i].innerText = '';
  cells[i].style.removeProperty('background-color');
  cells[i].addEventListener('click', turnClick, false);
 }
}

function turnClick(square) {
 turn(square.target.id, huPlayer)
}

function turn(squareId, player) {
 gameBoard[squareId] = player;
 document.getElementById(squareId).innerText = player;
}
```

```css
td {
 border:  2px solid #333;
 height:  100px;
 width:  100px;
 text-align:  center;
 vertical-align:  middle;
 font-family:  "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
 font-size:  70px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -155px;
 top: 50px;
}

table tr:first-child td {
 border-top: 0;
}

table tr:last-child td {
 border-bottom: 0;
}

table tr td:first-child {
 border-left: 0;
}

table tr td:last-child {
 border-right: 0;
}

.endgame {
  width: 200px;
  top: 120px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>tic tac toe</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td class="cell" id="0"></td>
   <td class="cell" id="1"></td>
   <td class="cell" id="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="cell" id="3"></td>
   <td class="cell" id="4"></td>
   <td class="cell" id="5"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="cell" id="6"></td>
   <td class="cell" id="7"></td>
   <td class="cell" id="8"></td>
  </tr>
  <div class="endgame">
   <div class="text">Cant see this text</div>
  </div>
  <button onclick="startGame()">Replay</button>
 </table>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hey guys it seems I cant view my div with the class endgame, dont now why this is, any ideas?

Comment: what browser do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the following line remove this to view the element. The `display` property specifies if/how an element is displayed. `display: none;` makes your element hidden.

```
document.querySelector(".endgame").style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from your js whats mean hide `.endgame` div:

```
document.querySelector(".endgame").style.display = "none";
```

OR use in other place when you want to make it show:

```
document.querySelector(".endgame").style.display = "block";
```